# How to set multi-conditions in an If statement for a pytorch tensor

Tags: python, if-statement, pytorch, conditional-statements

I have a pytorch tensor and want to mask part of it and put the masked section in an if statement. This is my tensor:

```
import torch
all_data = torch.tensor([[1.1, 0.4],
                         [1.7, 2.7],
                         [0.9, 0.7],
                         [0.9, 3.5],
                         [0.1, 0.5]])
if [(all_data[:,0]<1) & (all_data[:,1]<1)]: # I have two conditions
    print ('Masked')
else:
    print('Not_Masked')
```

this piece of code is not working correctly because it prints the whole tensor while I want to check the tensor row by row: the first and second rows do not fulfill the condition and I want to print `Not_Masked`. The third row fulfills and I wan to have `Masked` printed. It should go so on and so forth.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you should not place something in an `if`-statement unless you know how the expression evaluates in terms of `truthiness`. This is discussed e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/21012339

In this example, `[(all_data[:,0]<1) & (all_data[:,1]<1)]` is *always* truthy, because it is a list of non-zero length.

While I don't understand much about tensors and these conditions, hopefully the following edit shows how you can get the correct result using Python:

```
import torch

all_data = torch.tensor([[1.1, 0.4],
                         [1.7, 2.7],
                         [0.9, 0.7],
                         [0.9, 3.5],
                         [0.1, 0.5]])
conditionTensor = (all_data[:,0]<1) & (all_data[:,1]<1) # I have two conditions

print(conditionTensor)

for i,c in enumerate(conditionTensor):
    maskedstr = "Masked" if c else "Not_Masked"
    print(f"{i}: {maskedstr}")
```

`enumerate` is a kind of shortcut. You can view any list (and similar structure) and have both its indices and its elements at hand.

`format strings` are available in Python v3.6 and later. They let you embed expressions in strings.